# Which thread does Dialog.show() run on?

Tags: android, android-dialog

Does [Dialog.show()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#show()) method run on the UI thread or does it run on another thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialog is a UI component of Android. All UI components run on the UI thread. If you run it from a background thread, you need to have a looper so that dialog.show can work.